# PostgreSQL - set_config parameter is not being persisted between stored procedures when exception raised

Tags: postgresql, exception, stored-procedures, rollback

I'm converting an Oracle solution to PostgreSQL, where the Oracle solution makes use of PL/SQL global variables to assign error messages when an exception occurs in an inner procedure, so that they can be referenced in the outer procedure, for example (very basic):

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(1/0);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      gv_error_text := 'Failure during INNER_PRC. Oracle Error: '||SUBSTR(SQLERRM,1,512);
      RAISE ge_app_exception;
END;

PROCEDURE outer_prc IS
BEGIN
  inner_prc;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN ge_app_exception THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,gv_error_text);
END;
```

where **gv_error_text** and **ge_app_exception** are global within the context of the PL/SQL package.

For PostgreSQL, I am trying to use Configuration Parameters to do something similar, i.e.

1. Set the config parameter in the EXCEPTION block of INNER_PRC, using set_config
2. Read the config parameter in the EXCEPTION block of OUTER_PRC, using current_setting

However, OUTER_PRC is not seeing the new value, presumably due to the setting being rolled back in the WHEN OTHERS block

To demonstrate this using a very basic example, I have assigned the following parameter in postgresql.conf: **test.test_config = 'ORIGINAL_DEFAULT_VALUE'** and create the following two stored procedures:

```
DECLARE
  v_test_config VARCHAR(30);
  v_dbz         INTEGER;
BEGIN

  v_test_config := current_setting('test.test_config');
  RAISE NOTICE 'INNER_PRC: Starting test.test_config value: %',v_test_config;

  BEGIN
    PERFORM set_config('test.test_config','NEW_VALUE',false);
  END;

  v_test_config := current_setting('test.test_config');
  RAISE NOTICE 'INNER_PRC: Ending test.test_config value: %',v_test_config;

  --Raise Error
  v_dbz := 1/0;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN

      RAISE NOTICE 'INNER_PRC WHEN OTHERS: test.test_config value: %',v_test_config;

      PERFORM set_config('test.test_config','EXCEPTION_VALUE',false);

      v_test_config := current_setting('test.test_config');
      RAISE NOTICE 'INNER_PRC WHEN OTHERS: Ending test.test_config value: %',v_test_config;

      RAISE EXCEPTION USING ERRCODE = 'T2000';

END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE outer_prc () AS $$
DECLARE
  v_test_config VARCHAR(30);
BEGIN

  v_test_config := current_setting('test.test_config');
  RAISE NOTICE 'OUTER_PRC: Starting test.test_config value: %',v_test_config;

  CALL inner_prc();

  v_test_config := current_setting('test.test_config');
  RAISE NOTICE 'OUTER_PRC: Ending test.test_config value: %',v_test_config;


  EXCEPTION

    WHEN OTHERS THEN

      v_test_config := current_setting('test.test_config');
      RAISE NOTICE 'OUTER_PRC WHEN OTHERS: Ending test.test_config value: %',v_test_config;


END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
```

When I comment out **v_dbz := 1/0;** in INNER_PRC and run OUTER_PRC, the output is as expected:

```
psql:test.OUTER_PRC.sql:5: NOTICE:  OUTER_PRC: Starting test.test_config value: ORIGINAL_DEFAULT_VALUE
psql:test.OUTER_PRC.sql:5: NOTICE:  INNER_PRC: Starting test.test_config value: ORIGINAL_DEFAULT_VALUE
psql:test.OUTER_PRC.sql:5: NOTICE:  INNER_PRC: Ending test.test_config value: NEW_VALUE
psql:test.OUTER_PRC.sql:5: NOTICE:  OUTER_PRC: Ending test.test_config value: NEW_VALUE
```

but once I remove the comments, i.e. to trigger the error, the output becomes:

```
psql:test.OUTER_PRC.sql:5: NOTICE:  OUTER_PRC: Starting test.test_config value: ORIGINAL_DEFAULT_VALUE
psql:test.OUTER_PRC.sql:5: NOTICE:  INNER_PRC: Starting test.test_config value: ORIGINAL_DEFAULT_VALUE
psql:test.OUTER_PRC.sql:5: NOTICE:  INNER_PRC: Ending test.test_config value: NEW_VALUE
psql:test.OUTER_PRC.sql:5: NOTICE:  INNER_PRC WHEN OTHERS: test.test_config value: NEW_VALUE
psql:test.OUTER_PRC.sql:5: NOTICE:  INNER_PRC WHEN OTHERS: Ending test.test_config value: EXCEPTION_VALUE
psql:test.OUTER_PRC.sql:5: NOTICE:  OUTER_PRC WHEN OTHERS: Ending test.test_config value: ORIGINAL_DEFAULT_VALUE
```

i.e. test.test_config is assigned the new value in the EXCEPTION block of INNER_PRC, but in the EXCEPTION block of OUTER_PRC, it is being retrieved as its default value.

Any help/advice as to how to overcome this would be possible.

Alternatively, if there's another solution to achieve this behaviour without using config parameters, please let me know.

Thanks
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Like everything else, setting a placeholder parameter will be rolled back with the subtransaction. Look at this code:

```
SET my.param = 'before the call';
BEGIN
   CALL inner_proc();
EXCEPTION
   WHEN raise_exception THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION '%', current_setting('my.param');
END;
```

No matter what `inner_proc()` does, it will have been rolled back by the time when we enter the exception handler, so the exception will always say "before the call".

You will have to rewrite your code. One way to do this is to catch the exception in `inner_proc()` and return the error message as an output parameter.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz,. I was really hoping not to have to do that :-(